# PHP contact form program

Tags: gratis, php

I'm looking for a PHP contact form program that fits the following requirements.

1. Free
2. Secure
3. No attribution required
4. Works with PHP5 +
5. Very little or no CSS styling included in program
6. Allowed to edit/modify the code to fit your needs
7. Works without using WordPress or other CMS / not just a plugin for a CMS
8. Allow the user to fill in a form and submit it
9. Send notification by email to a group of selected emails (Admin)
10. Follow web standards, uses best practices and secure
11. Built in server side validation

The only one that I've found was [the FastSecureContactForm PHP script](http://www.fastsecurecontactform.com/download-php-script).

Has anyone used this? How did/does it work for you? I checked the [FAQ](http://www.fastsecurecontactform.com/faq-php-version), but wasn't able to find answers to some of my requirements.

Any other ones?

Comment: What should that "form program" do? You just described "compatibility details". I miss the "functionality" part (or the "user story" behind it, which might explain that part). Maybe you cross-check with [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) for what might be missing here, and then [edit] your question to fill the gaps? Thanks!

Comment: Just wondering, based on the requirement you have mentioned you can easily build that your self. All what you need is a single form, js validation, then pass everything to php, validate, send emails to admin, save to db. Unless you want to have a full featured Ticketing System like UserVoice which includes search and knowledge base then you can try something from this list -> (http://blog.neweb.co/9-free-open-source-ticket-systems/) until someone answers this question.

Comment: I think what the OP is looking for is defined fields, so that they can collect the information that they need (in addition to the typical user data such as IP, etc, that most implementations provide). Many give you a textbox and some sort of human verification, based on what the OP said they're evaluating, they want a contact form builder that works with WP that isn't made of Swiss cheese when it comes to what it lets through (note, the example also uses Akismet). I use said example implementation, and want something better myself.

Answer (score 1):

Would this work for you? http://css-tricks.com/serious-form-security/ 
The main purpose of this form is security. It's free, No attribution required. Works with PHP5 +. Made with JQery. Works without using WordPress or other CMS / not just a plugin for a CMS.